# Efficient representation of low-complexity integer vectors

Tags: matlab

Let `V` be a vector of integers, and let *L* be the length of `V`.

Now, suppose that the number *N* of *distinct* values in `V` is *much smaller* than *L*.

One may also assume that `V` is sorted, so that it can be construed as the concatenation of *N* consecutive constant "blocks".

Lastly, one may assume that, once initialized, `V` is henceforth *read-only* (aka *immutable*).

(In the case I'm working with at the moment, *L* is between 10<sup>6</sup> and 10<sup>7</sup>, and *N* is about 20.)

It is wasteful to store such low-complexity data in a standard MATLAB *L*-long vector.  Does MATLAB have any *built-in*<sup>1</sup> data structure that

1. has the same interface as a regular vector (e.g. one can read its *k*-th element with the expression `V(k)`, its last element with `V(end)`, ranges of locations with `V(p:q)`, etc.).
2. uses much less storage space than *L* × the size of an integer.

?

---

BTW, the problem here is reminiscent to that of sparse-array representation, but not quite the same (at least AFAICT).

---

OK, here's my solution, based on gariepy's answer:

```
block_sizes = [5, 4, 3, 2];
block_values = 1000 + (1:numel(block_sizes));
interpolation_table = [0 cumsum(block_sizes)];
V = @(i) interp1(interpolation_table, [NaN block_values], i, 'next');
V(0)
ans =
   NaN

V(1:5)
ans =
        1001        1001        1001        1001        1001

V(6:9)
ans =
        1002        1002        1002        1002

V(10:12)
ans =
        1003        1003        1003

V(13:14)
ans =
        1004        1004

V(15)
ans =
   NaN
```

It has a tiny wart, though:

```
V(end)
ans =
        1001
```

(It would have been better if it raised an exception when given `end` as arguments, rather than give a completely crazy answer.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Of course, I know that I can always can try to roll my own implementation of such a thing, but I prefer not to re-invent wheels if I can avoid it.</sup>

Comment: The short answer is no. Depending on how you are using this vector, though, there may be a way to accomplish what you want without ever storing the entire vector in memory. If you give us an example use case then maybe we could help.

Comment: @Suever: I gave an example already: *L* = 1 million, *N* = 20.  Those are the only parameters than matter in the problem.

Comment: Right, but is your goal simply to create this vector or are you trying to *do something* with the vector. If it's just to create it, then you will need to roll your own implementation. If you want to do something, then there may be a built-in way.

Comment: @Suever: Now I see what you mean.  No, I'm looking for the data structure in general.  I guess the answer is "No".  That pretty much settles it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible method to represent this data is an interpolation table.

Assume `vec` is your length L vector.  First, count the number of occurrences:

```
[num_occurrences, y_values] = hist(vec, unique(vec));
```

Then, build the interpolation representation:

```
interp_table = zeros(1,length(y_values) + 1);
interp_table(1) = 1;
y_values(end+1) = y_values(end) + 1;  % Need to create a "fake" value at the end of the interpolation table
for i = 2:length(y_values)
    interp_table(i) = interp_table(i-1) + num_occurrences(i-1);
end
```

Finally, define a function handle to give you the "array-like" access you want.

```
my_fun = @(x) interp1(interp_table, y_values, x, 'previous');
```

Example:

```
>> vec = [1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ];
>> my_fun(1)
ans =
     1
>> my_fun(2)
ans =
     1
>> my_fun(3)
ans =
     2
>> my_fun(6)
ans =
     2
>> my_fun(7)
ans =
     2
>> my_fun(8)
ans =
     3
>> my_fun(17)
ans =
     3
>> my_fun(18)  %% This is vec(L+1), so it should never be needed
ans =
     4
>> my_fun(19)  %% Above index L+1, values are not defined
ans =
   NaN
```

The examples demonstrate a minor caveat: values above my_fun(L) should not be used, where L is the length of the original vector that is being represented by the interpolation table.  So this gives you array-like access, though you cannot directly calculate the "length" of this interpolation table.

EDIT: note that you CAN do ranges with this interpolation function:

```
>> my_fun(1:17)
ans =
  Columns 1 through 15
     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
  Columns 16 through 17
     3     3
```

Comment: Great idea.  I took it and modified it a bit.  See my EDIT.